# Proving that $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z}{n(1+n|z|^{2})}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> How can one prove that $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{z}{n(1+n|z|^{2})}$$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{C}$ ?

My attempt was to let $z=x+iy$, then consider $$|\dfrac{z}{n(1+n|z|^{2})}|=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}{\sqrt{(n^{2}x^{2}+n)^{2}+(n^{2}y)^{2}}}.$$

which looks like a mess. The main idea was to try to find an upper bound, $M_{k}$ so that I can apply the Weierstrass M-test. If I can show that the upper bound, $M_{k}$ is convergent (which is often simple by using root test etc.), I will be able to conclude that $f(z)$ converges uniformly.

Is there a simpler or more elegant way I can approach this question and if my approach is correct, can someone kindly guide me to find the required upper bound?

Comment: For every $z$ and $n$, $$1+n|z|^2\geqslant2\sqrt n|z|$$ hence $$\left|\frac{z}{n(1+n|z|^2)}\right|\leqslant\frac1{2n\sqrt n}$$

Comment: Hi Did, thanks for your response. May I know how did you obtain the first inequality: $1+n|z|^{2} \geq 2\sqrt{n}|z|$?

Comment: @Cleytus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means.

Comment: $(1-\sqrt n |z|)^2 ≥ 0$

Comment: Did, Lucas, Martin R thanks for your inputs - I've figured it out. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: Indeed, AM-GM is a much too large hammer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding an upper bound for
$$
\left|\frac{z}{n(1+n|z|^{2})}\right |
$$
uniformly for $z \in \Bbb C$ is equivalent to finding an upper bound
for 
$$ \tag{*}
 \frac{r}{n(1+nr^2)}
$$
uniformly for $r \ge 0$, therefore using the $z = x+iy$ representation
is not needed and makes things only more complicated.

In order to estimate $(*)$, one can use the [“inequality of arithmetic and geometric means”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), as @Did demonstrated in [above comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2673323/proving-that-fz-sum-limits-n-1-infty-dfraczn1nz2-converges/2673351#comment5521353_2673323). But if you don't come
up with that idea, just proceed systematically and
 determine (for fixed $n$) the maximum of the function
$$
 \phi(r) =  \frac{r}{n(1+nr^2)} \, , \quad r \ge 0 \, .
$$
It turns out that the (unique) maximum is at $r = \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$,
and therefore
$$
\left|\frac{z}{n(1+n|z|^{2})}\right | \le \frac{1}{2 n^{3/2}} \, .
$$
for all $z \in \Bbb C$.

Comment: Thanks for this new perspective, Martin.