# Complex analysis prove uniform convergence question

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{z}{n(1 + n|z|^2)}.
$$

I need to prove this series converges uniformly on $\mathbb{C}$, so I try to prove this by M-test.

[image]

I am not sure is this correct, since I am not familiar with complex analysis uniform convergence.

Comment: A question about the same series was asked yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2673323/proving-that-fz-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fraczn1nz2-converges.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct, for several reasons:

- What you call $M_k$ has not $k$ in it. You should have called it $M_n$.
- *Of course* each $M_n$ is finite. What does that matter? What matters is that their *sum* is finite.
- It turns out that $\sup_{z\in\mathbb C}\left|\frac z{n\bigl(1+n|z|^2\bigr)}\right|=\frac1{2n^{3/2}}$. So, you should have taken $M_n=\frac1{2n^{3/2}}$. Since$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n^{3/2}}$$convverges, your series converges uniformly.

Comment: I think there is a factor $1/2$ missing in the supremum, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2673323/42969

Comment: @MartinR I've edited my answer. Thank you.